# cd to a path variable in .bash_profile with spaces, without using quotes

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, cd, bash

In my `.bash_profile`, I've got: `dl="/Users/gary/Downloads`. When I go to Terminal and type `cd $dl`, it goes to the dir, as expected.

But when I have the following line in `.bash_profile`:

`applib="/Users/gary/Library/Application Support"`

And I type `cd $applib` then it doesn't work, due to the space in the path.

I know that `cd "$applib"` *does* work, though, but is there a way to make it so that I don't need the quotes? Otherwise, I'd have to remember which of my path variables need the quotes and which don't, for instance.

Comment: Type `cd "$gm"`, otherwise you get word splitting

Comment: Yes I noted that in my third paragraph already.

Comment: No, there's no way to prevent future word splitting when just assigning the variable. You could make an alias like `alias gm='cd "/Users/gary/Library/Application Support"'`, and then just type `gm`.

Comment: You might want to consider using `zsh` instead of `bash`. Its default behavior is to not perform word splitting on parameter expansions, so `cd $applib` would work just fine without quotes. It also supports a setting that allows `$applib`, if it's not an executable, to be be short for `cd $applib`, so it's even less to type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are expanded before word splitting. There's no other way how to keep the spaces than quoting. See `man bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion,  parameter,  variable  and  arithmetic expansion  and  command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Instead of remembering when to use the quotes, use them always. They don't harm the values with no spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Use the quotes; that's what they're for. You don't need to remember which paths need quotes and which don't; just use them consistently:

```
cd "$dl"

cd "$applib"
```